# Adding categories to a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many, relationships

I've had some issues with this before when creating applications and I think I'm starting to run into it again, hence I'm asking this on StackOverflow to save me a lot of time.
I've spent the last few weeks setting up a perfected product model for my system. The model performs exactly as I want it to and has several complex features (such as search via sunspot). I wanted to setup the category to product structure before I started this heavy development - however struggling with this kind of thing was just putting me off creating the application so I got straight into the product structure.
Now I've got the product model setup - what would be the easiest way to add a category ownership to encompass the products? (All products have a category_id column which store their father category id)
My plan is to have the category index to be a list of all the categories, the category show to be a list of the products inside that category and the product show being the view of the actual product. This would eliminate the product index and so I'll have to come up with a way to port the search feature (sunspot) from my index view to the category show somehow.
As for the actual listing of the products - I assume I'll have to do some kind of partial? (I don't know a lot about it).

Most basically, my relationships are planned to be:
category:

```
has_many :products
```

product:

```
has_one :category
```

My products then have a category_id column to store the ID of it's parent category.

**Any tips on how to accomplish the relationships (category show to list the products etc)?**

Best Regards,

Joe

Comment: Sounds like you want a relationship between the category and the product, do the Rails relationships not do what you want?

Comment: A has_many relation would do fine most basically - but I'm not sure how to actually get everything to work smoothly (like basically transferring the current tutorial index page to the category show page).

Comment: Ok well typically StackOverflow works best when you ask a specific and direct question. Is there any way you can sum this up to a single question? Perhaps rewrite your post, it seems like you have a lot in there and it might be daunting to some people who want to help. :)

Comment: If you have a specific question, you will get a specific answer. If you have a vague question it might not get answered at all. Amending your question to be more to the point would help, and pasting in some concise examples of the model or models you're dealing with would frame the question better.

Comment: I've added some hard code showing the relationships I'm looking for - hopefully this should entice more answers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships like the one you're wanting are built into [ActiveRecord support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Understanding the model relationships in Rails is critical to doing anything in Rails that's non-trivial, so study up.

Also, the relationship you're looking for is something like:

product:
`belongs_to :category`

category:
`has_many :products`

Comment: I see. How would you recommend implementing this relationship outside the models?

Comment: I don't quite follow - are you not using a database? Is that why you don't want to use ActiveRecord? If you're using a database to store your data, I have no idea why you wouldn't use ActiveRecord.

Comment: I corrected a mistake in my answer - I had my relationships backwards.

Comment: I can set up the relationships via the models - but I'm not quite sure how to then transfer everything in the views and such so that the products are actually nested in the category show views and such...

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question, because the answer to how relationships, controllers, views, etc. work together is that you need to go through the Rails tutorials and follow along with them. These are among the first things you will learn when going through Rails tutorials. One great resource I can point you to is the book about Rails, written by the people who created it: http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Development-Rails-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356549/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1313189676&sr=8-1

Comment: There's no short answer to your question - you need to first learn the fundamentals of Rails - which is eat least a few chapters of study from a good book, or several days of work through online tutorials.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll try to work in a few more Railscasts (that's pretty much all I'm learning off at the moment) and just generally do a bit more learning then I guess. Any general tips for me?

Comment: Gotcha - yeah the rails casts are fantastic. Other than the book, and reading other people's code to learn, it'll just take time and some patience.